# Getting TeX Live Utility to recognize new TeX Live Version (2021) on OS X 10.11 (El Capitan)

Tags: texlive, mactex, paths, signatures, tex-live-utility

Since the MacTeX-2021 package does not support my old OS version I have manually installed TeX Live 2021 via the Unix installer as described on [Unix Install of TeX Live 2021](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html). The installation worked fine, but the second step that would configure TeX so TeX Live Utility and various GUI programs can find it fails, because the installer of TeXDist-2021 says "TeXDist-2021.pkg can't be installed because its digital signature is invalid". I have redownloaded that pkg several times and also tried mactex-texdist-20210226.pkg from CTAN with the same outcome. I'm pretty sure the signature is fine and it's my side that poses the problem, which is kinda corroborated by [this](https://forum.xojo.com/t/invalid-signature-in-el-capitan/62862). But that would also mean I can't really "fix" this signature problem I guess.

Right now TLU doesn't see/show the new version (neither in the prefpane nor in TLU itself). Is there maybe a way I could manually do what TeXDist-2021 would do?

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: I have the same problem. Any help will be valuable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to right click on the `.pkg` and then choose 'Open'?

Comment: Another way might be to go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General and select Allow apps downloaded from Anywhere. No idea if the works on Mojave, however.

Comment: I am running an older version to accommodate my OS.  You can copy the links to servers hosting the older versions from here: https://www.tug.org/mactex/faq/3-4.html, for example: ftp://ftp.tug.org/historic/systems/mactex/.  I found the 2016 build to work well in my case (I have OSX 10.8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a new section "If TeXDist-2021 Fails" in the page.
https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-unix-download.html

Comment: Thank you so much..that shell script worked!